# How to upload images using Elastic Beanstalk with django-cms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-cms

When I use the djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_picture plugin to upload images, it is creating a broken link:

```
<img src="/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/b9/a0/b9a04dc2-ac02-4ad6-a94d-d950629e4bce/team_1.png__763x759_q85_subsampling-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid cms-plugin cms-plugin-48">
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Tried doing this with both BASE_DIR and DATA_DIR with the same broken link result. No image displays. I'm not sure if static files has anything to do with this, and I've already tried to follow the instructions from [realpython](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#using-s3-for-media-storage)

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a broken link, it looks perfectly valid. Your issue is more likely the file isn't being put where django is then looking for it. Your `MEDIA_ROOT` is where it'll be looked for, so you need to find where it actually goes. What is your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` setting?

Comment: Finally figured it out.  Way more complex than I thought, but it works beautifully. Will post the answer that worked for me, maybe it will help others out with using Django on EB.